# jquery selecting child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

The setup.

I am using MVC 5, and I have created a view with data sent in the form of a viewmodel.

With in this view I have rendered a List object as stacked div's, as seen below.

As you will see, I am displaying hidden fields, so that the viewModel send back the data to the controller on submit.

```
<div class="row item-row">
    <div class="small-4 columns">
        objType
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 columns">
        <input id="object_0__Id" name="object[0].Id" type="hidden" value="999999">
        <input id="object_0__Reference" name="object[0].Reference" type="hidden" value="myRef">myRef
        <input id="object_0__RecordChanged" name="object[0].RecordChanged" type="hidden" value="NoChange">
    </div>
    <div class="small-2 columns remove-item">
        <button class="button tiny expand centre button-gray" onclick="javascript: RemoveItem(999999);">Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row item-row">
    <div class="small-4 columns">
        objType
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 columns">
        <input id="object_1__Id" name="object[1].Id" type="hidden" value="000001">
        <input id="object_1__Reference" name="object[1].Reference" type="hidden" value="myRef">myRef
        <input id="object_1__RecordChanged" name="object[1].RecordChanged" type="hidden" value="NoChange">
    </div>
    <div class="small-2 columns remove-item">
        <button class="button tiny expand centre button-gray" onclick="javascript: RemoveItem(000001);">Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ok, so the javascript function RemoveItem is:

```
function RemoveItem(id)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var element = $(event.target).closest('.item-row');

    $(element).closest('DeedReference_0__RecordChanged').val('Deleted');   ***** This is what I am trying to do.

    $(element).hide();
}
```

From the above, when I click on say RemoveItem(00001), the variable element contains the following:

```
<div class="small-4 columns">
    objType
</div>
<div class="small-6 columns">
    <input id="object_0__Id" name="object[0].Id" type="hidden" value="000001">
    <input id="object_0__Reference" name="object[0].Reference" type="hidden" value="myRef">myRef
    <input id="object_0__RecordChanged" name="object[0].RecordChanged" type="hidden" value="NoChange">
</div>
<div class="small-2 columns remove-item">
    <button class="button tiny expand centre button-gray" onclick="javascript: RemoveItem(000001);">Remove</button>
</div>
```

The value I need to update is object[0].RecordChanged, but at this moment in time, I do not know the index value. So I was planning on using the ends with selector, but am not able to get it to work.

I have got as far as:

```
$(event.target).closest('.item-row').children()[1]
```

But this gives me the div, since I have tried:

```
$(event.target).closest('.item-row').children()[1].Find('Id*"__RecordChanged"')
$(event.target).closest('.item-row [id*="RecordChanged"]')
$(event.target).closest('.item-row:[id*="RecordChanged"])
```

And using the variable

```
$(element [id*="RecordChanged"])
$(element [id$="RecordChanged"])
```

**UPDATE**

Fixed bug in code that was suggesting that I was looking at the wrong index.

Also, If I click the remove button for RemoveItem(000001), I am trying to update the value object_0__RecordChanged.

Comment: `closest` finds the closest ancestor of an element which matches a given selector. Do you want `children` or `find` instead?

Comment: just fixed at issue with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed view model  to have an index property. Then changed placed the HTML.EditorFor within a foreach loop enabling me to populate the index property before it is rendered out.

Then the code was changed from:

```
function RemoveItem(id)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var element = $(event.target).closest('.item-row');

    $(element).closest('DeedReference_0__RecordChanged').val('Deleted');   ***** This is what I am trying to do.

    $(element).hide();
}
```

to:

```
function RemoveItem(id)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var recordChanged = '#object_' + id + '__RecordChanged';
    $(recordChanged).val('Deleted');
    var element = $(event.target).closest('.item-row');
    $(element).hide();
}
```

Much simpler!